# Top 90% Average Query losing best performers

Tags: ms-access

I need to collect the average score of the top 90% of the records from the last 365 days from tblQAScore for a form.

Table (selected fields only):

```
|Technician  |Date        |Score       |
|1           |1/5/17      |8           |
|1           |1/6/17      |9           |
|1           |1/7/17      |7           |
|1           |1/9/17      |8           |
|1           |1/1/18      |10          |
|1           |1/3/18      |9           |
|1           |1/1/17      |8           |
|1           |1/5/17      |9           |
|1           |1/6/17      |7           |
|1           |1/9/17      |8           |
|2           |1/1/17      |8           |
|2           |1/2/17      |7           |
|2           |1/6/17      |9           |
|2           |1/9/17      |8           |
|2           |1/1/18      |10          |
|3           |1/3/18      |9           |
|3           |1/1/17      |8           |
|3           |1/5/17      |9           |
|3           |1/6/17      |7           |
|3           |1/9/17      |8           |
```

Expected Query Result

```
|Technician  |AvgOfScore  |
|1           |8.44        | 'drop lowest of 10 scores before calculating avg
|2           |9           | 'only 3 scores in last 365 days so none dropped
|3           |8.2         | 'only 5 scores total so none dropped
```

Recently I've added two new Technicians that are looked up  in tblQAScore, both of whom have records therein, all with "10" (the max) as their scores. For some reason these are not appearing in my top 90% Average query...

```
SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT tblQAScore.Technician, Avg(tblQAScore.Score) AS AvgOfScore
FROM tblQAScore
WHERE (((tblQAScore.Exclude)=False) AND ((tblQAScore.QADate)>Date()-365))
GROUP BY tblQAScore.Technician
ORDER BY Avg(tblQAScore.Score);
```

This means that the averages don't appear on the user form either, which was kind of the point.

Is the problem because those two are new Technicians, so their ID is a higher (later) number, dropping them out of the top 90%? If so, how do I make sure it's the top 90% of tblQAScore records by score that are then averaged?

---

Edit: After further playing around, partly inspired by the comments, it's clear that the bottom(formerly top) 10% of *technicians* is what's being dropped. How can I drop the bottom 10% of *each* technician's *score* set?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sample data and expected result are essential for this question. [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: I think setting the ORDER BY to descending may fix it.

Comment: jshort - thanks, that's illustrated part of the problem. I was indeed dropping the top records *instead* of the bottom because of what you mentioned. The remaining issue is that I'm dropping the bottom record sets, rather than the bottom records from each set.